# Kate replaces text instead of indenting when typing Tab on selected lines

Tags: kate, indentation, tabulation

I tried to change all the indentation settings to fix another problem yesterday, but now I have the following problem and I don't know which setting causes it.

If I select lines and type Tab, I would expect the selected lines to be indented. Instead, the selection is replaced with a tabulation. For example, I start with:

```
aa
bb
cc
```

Then I select a part (what's between [ and ] is the selected part):

```
aa
b[b
c]c
```

Then I press Tab (---> represents a tabulation), I expect this:

```
aa
--->bb
--->cc
```

But I get this instead:

```
aa
b--->c
```

How can I revert this behaviour? I'm using Kate 21.12.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the main window, `settings` -> `Configure Kate`. In the sidebar, go to `Editing` and there go the the tab `Indentation`.

Under `Indentation Actions` select `Increase indentation level if in leading blank space` (this is the default action).

[image: Indentation settings]

Comment: sorry, had to edit the question as I swapped the options while testing it. (Gave the wrong answer first)

Comment: Yesss, thank you! However the text is misleading. I thought "if no selection exists" meant something like "if nothing is selected", which is not my case, since I did select a part of the text, no?